# How to add the total from a property inside an object inside an array that is dynamically created - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I've been struggling with this for a week now and can't seem to find a solution: I have a empty that is populated with objects `(ng-click="AddProduct(product)")`. This product object has a property called subtotal which is an integer. I want to every time I add a product into the array, the total to be update, however after the products have been added to the array, the user add or subtract either a fixed amount or a percentage to the total (like extra charges or give a discount) so I created a total function like so:

```
$scope.total = function () {

    var total = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.orderContent.products, function (s) {

        total += parseFloat(s.subtotal);

        if ($scope.orderContent.totals.extras.ServiceCharge) {

            total = total + $scope.orderContent.totals.extras.ServiceCharge;

        }
        if ($scope.orderContent.totals.extras.ServiceChargePercentage) {

            total = (total / 100) * $scope.orderContent.totals.extras.ServiceChargePercentage + total;

        }

    });

    total = total.toFixed(2);

    return total;
};
```

The problem I\m getting is that sometime the above works (like as soon I finished add the product to the cart and then add a value to the total it all works fine) and sometime it doesn't (if I add a value, delete and add another one, it seems the original value is still hanging and is added together with my second value)

What am I missing here?

**EDIT: I've created a Plunker to demonstrate the issue**

http://plnkr.co/edit/oiwsnO?p=preview

Comment: when do you call `$scope.total()` ? could you add more context code?

Comment: Reproducing this in a fiddle/plunk will get you much more help.

Comment: @nilsK the total() is in the template like <div ng-model="total()"></div>

Comment: @Nikos I'll be adding a plnkr later.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you use ng-bind instead of ng-model?

```
<div ng-bind="total()"></div>
```

Comment: yes right, ng-bind for one way binding $scope -> view and ng-model for two way binding $scope <-> view

Comment: @Michale Hi Michael. I've posted my reply from my phone. In fact Im not using `ng-model` nor `ng-bind` I'm using within the html instead: `<div>{{total() | currency}}</div>`. Anyway, this is not the issue. If you look at my Plunker you'll see that when you add a value to be added it doesn't add up.